# subtracting values in one column based on another column

Tags: awk

I have input file as follows

```
100A 2000
100B 150
100C 800
100A 1000
100B 100
100C 300
```

I want to subtract values in column 2 for each uniq value in column 1 
so the out put should look like

```
100A 1000
100B 50
100C 500
```

I have tried

```
 awk '{if(!a[$1])a[$1]=$2; else a[$1]=$2-a[$1]}END{ for(i in a)print i" " a[i]}' file
```

but the out put is :

```
100A 0
100B 0
100C 0
```

please advise

Comment: What should happen if the value in the first column is repeated more than once?

Comment: in that case I want to take the first and the last occurrences

Comment: None of the solutions posted would do that, all they do is work for the 2-entry sample you provided (and all except mine unnecessarily save half the input in an array and then produce output in random order rather than strictly the order the key values were read which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: @EdMorton: your solution works for me but I have a query which I have posted in the comment section of your solution

Comment: @user3369871 - as Ed said, you're out of luck for >2 samples with existing solutions, including his. I've just updated mine to handly your first/last occurrence condition, as well as provide a mechanism for controlling order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many (slight) variations on the same theme.

```
awk '
  !($1 in a) {a[$1]=$2; next}
  {a[$1]-=$2}
  END {for (i in a) printf "%s %d\n",i,a[i]}
' input.txt
```

Stack it up as a one-liner if you like.

Remember that awk structure consists of multiple `condition { statement }` pairs, so you can sometimes express your requirements more elegantly than using an `if..else`. (Not saying that this is the case here - this is a simple enough awk script that it probably doesn't matter, unless you're a purist. :] )

Also, beware of testing for values the way you've done in the condition in your `if` in the question. Note that `a[$1]` *both* tests whether the value at that array index is non-zero *and* causes the index to exist with a null value if it didn't previously exist. If you want to check for index existence, use `$1 in a`.

---

Update based on a comment on your question...

If you want to subtract the *last* from the *first* entry, ignoring the ones in between, then you need to keep a record of both your firsts and your lasts. Something like this might suffice.

```
awk '
  !($1 in a){a[$1]=$2;next}
  {b[$1]=$2}
  END {for(i in b)if(i in a)print i,a[i]-b[i]}
' input.txt
```

Note that as Ed mentioned, this produces output in random order. If you want the output ordered, you'll need an additional array to track of the order.  For example, this will use order that items are first seen:

```
awk '
  !($1 in a) {
    a[$1]=$2;
    o[++n]=$1;
    next
  }
  {
    b[$1]=$2
  }
  END {
    for (n=1;n<=length(o);n++)
      print o[n],a[o[n]]-b[o[n]]
  }
' i
```

Note that the `length()` function being used to determine the number of elements in an array is not universal amongst dialects of awk, but it does work in both gawk and [one-true-awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/master/FIXES#L322) (used in FreeBSD and others).

Comment: I agree but I have assigned a value a[$1]=$2  when the index did not exist  then whats wrong with my solution ?

Comment: Your test was `if(!a[$1])`, which does not test for nonexistence, it causes the index to exist (if it doesn't already) and tests for a value of zero. I'm not sure why you would be getting the results you mentioned in your question, but you've got your subtraction backwards. You're subtracting the second value from the first, so when I run your sample code I see negative numbers (1000 - 2000, 100 - 150, 300 - 800).

Comment: they can be negative as I have to find the integer difference , I just realized that my solution is working too and there is nothing wrong with my solution I was just running it with a wrong input file

Comment: No, there is something wrong with your solution, it will fail when the first $2 value encountered is zero. See @ghoti's comment for why.

Comment: @Ed, my input data does not expect $2 to be zero but  that's worth mentioning , thanks for that .

Comment: FYI length(array) is now POSIX so generally considered portable these days. You could have used `for (n=1;n in o;n++)` instead though to guarantee portability to all awks, and you don't need to test for `o[n] in a` as it's impossible for it not to be.

Comment: @EdMorton, ah, thanks for that, I hadn't thought of using that particular condition in a for loop.

Comment: You're welcome. I use it a lot but you just have to be sure your array is dense to use it. If you have array indices 1, 2, 4, 5 populated then a loop `for (i=1;i<=5;i++) print a[i]` will print 5 times while a loop `for (i=1;i in a;i++) print a[i]` will only print the first 2 items then quit because `i in a` is false when i=3. Of course `i<=length(a)` would also have a problem in that case as it wouldn't print the 5th value.

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner does the job:

```
 awk '{if($1 in a)a[$1]=a[$1]-$2;else a[$1]=$2}
      END{for(x in a) print x, a[x]}' file
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using if/else rather than the implicit structure that awk provides with `condition { statement }` constructs?

Answer (score 1):

In awk. Using conditional operator for value placing/subtraction to keep it tight:

```
$ awk '{ a[$1]+=($1 in a?-$2:$2) } END{ for(i in a)print i, a[i] }' file
100A 1000
100B 50
100C 500
```

Explained:

```
{ 
    a[$1]+=($1 in a?-$2:$2)  # if $1 in a already, subtract from it 
                                # otherwise add value to it
} 
END { 
    for(i in a)              # go thru all a
        print i, a[i]          # and print keys and values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample input you provided, all you need is:

```
$ awk '$1 in a{print $1, a[$1]-$2} {a[$1]=$2}' file
100A 1000
100B 50
100C 500
```

If that's not all you need then provide more truly representative sample input/output that includes the cases where that's not good enough.

Comment: Thanks Ed that works , Is this a way to implement if -else  in awk's condition block   where {print $1, a[$1]-$2} is executed when  $1 in a evaluates to true and {a[$1]=$2}  acts as else and executed when   $1 in a  evaluates to false ?

Comment: No, for there to be an else you'd insert `;next` before the first `}`. Right now the assignment happens for every line, it just functionally doesn't matter that that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'a[$1]{a[$1]=a[$1]-$2; next} {a[$1]=$2} END{for(v in a){print v, a[v]}}' file
```